# R snow rlecuyer: apply function with temporary seed

Tags: r, random, snow

I want to apply a function in parallel using `snow::clusterApply`. My function uses a temporary (pre-defined) seed in one part of the function but should maintain independent random numbers in general. The temporary seeds differ for each "job".

I can do the following:

```
# setting up cluster of type="SOCK"
library(snow)
cl <- makeSOCKcluster(2)

# this is my function
myfu <- function(seed){
    # temporary seed:
    x <- R.utils::withSeed(rnorm(10),seed)
    # more calculation with independent RNG:
    y <- x*rnorm(10)
    return(list(stays=x,changes=y))
}

# run example:
seed <- 1:4
data.frame(clusterApply(cl,seed,myfu))
# reproduce
data.frame(clusterApply(cl,seed,myfu))

stopCluster(cl)
```

However, following the link given in the "Uniform Random Number Generation in SNOW Clusters" section in the snow package documentation (http://homepage.stat.uiowa.edu/~luke/R/cluster/cluster.html), I read that "The default random number generators are likely to be quite correlated" and one should use extra packages such as e.g. the package `rlecuyer`.

Now, if I try to include that in my code, `set.seed` or `withSeed` are no use any more:

```
# setting up cluster of type="SOCK"
library(snow)
library(rlecuyer)
cl <- makeSOCKcluster(2)

# setup RNG Stream
clusterSetupRNGstream(cl,seed=1:6)

# run example:
seed <- 1:4
data.frame(clusterApply(cl,seed,myfu))
# can't reproduce
data.frame(clusterApply(cl,seed,myfu))

stopCluster(cl)
```

How can I work around `set.seed` or `withSeed` in parallel when I need to call them on a job basis and not prior to the `clusterApply` call?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me. Using `kind="L'Ecuyer-CMRG"` when calling `set.seed`/`withSeed` solves (of course) my problem.